# Launch an Activity from Android ListView and populate based on selection

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, click

I currently have an Android ListView class that displays a list of about 20 topics (Strings). I need to be able to click each button on the list and have that button open up a view specific to that topic.

For example, if this was a recipe list, then the layout for all of the recipe views could be the same, but when the user clicks a specific recipe from the list, then the program must load that recipe into the common layout and bring the user to that view.

I have the OnItemClickListener working I think, but I'm not sure how to implement the rest.

Will I need a new activity and layout for each recipe? Is there an easier way to implement this without making dozens of identical layout and activity files?

Also, how will I populate the view with the recipe?

Thanks much appreciated for any helpful thoughts!

--- Some relevant code: The Listview Activity Code

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, studiesList);  

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );    
    mainListView.setClickable(true);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id) { 

            switch( position )
            {
               case 0:  Intent intent = new Intent(StudyActivity.this, pos.class); 
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
```

The SimpleRow.xml File: (The buttons for the list)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make a serializable recipe class with some attributes, and then make new objects of that class for each of the 20 recipes.

I assume you'd have something like

```
public class Recipe extends Serializable{ 
private String name; 
private String ingredients; 

public Recipe(String name, String ingredients){
this.name = name;
this.ingredients = ingredients;
}
```

}

Then make an array list of these objects

```
ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
recipes.add(new Recipe("Chicken Curry", "Random cooking instructions"));
```

and use that arraylist in your list adapter.

Then in your onItemClickListener you'l need something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, recipeDisplay.class)
i.putExtra("recipe",  listAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

and in your recipe display class just recieve the intent and use the object to populate your activity fields.

```
Intent intent = getIntent():
intent.getSerializableExtra("recipe");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you will want to do is open the recipe in a new Activity, which will can have a standard "recipe" view.

To pass data to the new Activity, you can add extras (see [Intents and Intent Filters- Extras](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#extras) from the API docs) to the Intent that will launch the new activity. You can pass an int or a String that identifies the recipe you want.

The basic outline for passing extras in an Intent is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in the new Activity you can get those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras.hasExtra("EXTRA_ID")) {
    int value = extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
}
```

Use that value to load the recipe from whatever source you are getting your data from, and you should be all set!